# Fast character detection

Tags: text, image-processing, ocr

I don't want to know what it says, and it will not be dealing with any distortion like a CAPTCHA, I just want to know if a *bunch* of images contain any text.

This is something that will be running on a couple of idle Linux servers, and a cron job will process a large batch of images multiple times a day.

One of the things I want to do in the process, is discard any images with text in them. I don't mind some false positives, but I would like to get as close to a zero-percent fail rate when it comes to identifying images with text that should be discarded as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Tesseract-OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is what google use for Google Books. Give it a try.

Comment: This seems a little heavy for what I'm looking to do, I may come back to it though if I can find nothing lighter. :)